# Getting data from mysql and drawing a chart

Tags: php, mysql, date, highcharts

I have a temperature logger that stores a float value in mysql database, with the time and date of reading. Now I would like to use highcharts and display the values instead of in a table in a chart.

I have found  an example on http://blueflame-software.com/using-highcharts-with-php-and-mysql/, but when I set my values I get this:

[image]

When I was getting through the code I have noticed difference in date and time format (format that I am using yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss). I have changed the line

```
  date= Date.pars(line[0]+ ' ISO');
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the datetime format in your data.php.

```
$t = date_create(line[0]);
echo date_format($t, 'l, F j, Y H:i:s');
```

This should return something like this:

```
Tuesday, May 3, 2016 10:00:00
```

Comment: If i add this to data.php, the return i get: Sunday,October 9,2016 23:01:282016-09-17 19:24:04 28.598.

Comment: What do you want? Can you specify more and add your code to the question?

Comment: This is not a format that Highcharts will understand.

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts takes an integer value as the `x` value in a `datetime` axis, in the form of epoch time, in milliseconds.

You can use PHPs `strtotime` function, and multiply the result by 1,000.

Ref:

- http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes
- http://www.epochconverter.com/
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php